# Invalid value for key attachdbfilename after renaming connectionString

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am building the sample MvcMovie tutorial for ASP.NET MVC 4. I'm using EntityFramework Code First features and created a connectionString as follows.

```
<add name="MoveDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDictionary|\Movies2.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Everything worked fine at this point. But then I realized that I named my connection string MoveDBContext instead of MovieDBContext and, being the perfectionist I renamed it. After doing this I now receive an error in my MoviesController/Index method.

```
 public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Movies.ToList()); // Error: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'
    }
...
}
```

If I change the name back to MoveDBContext the error goes away.

Can anyone tell me where this original name is being referenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF, by default, looks for a connection string with the same name as the type that extends DbContext.

Or, better put by [Scott](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx):

> By default, when you create a DbContext class with EF code-first, it
>   will look for a connection-string that matches the name of the
>   context-class.  Since we named our context class “NerdDinners”, it
>   will by default look for and use the above “NerdDinners” database
>   connection-string when it is instantiated within our ASP.NET
>   application.

**Edit:**

After looking closer, I think your connection string is the problem. You've got `DataDictionary` instead of `DataDirectory`. Try this (line feeds added for readability):

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                       AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;
                       Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: My class is named correctly as MovieDBContext. (not MoveDBContext).

Comment: @Primc - Are you specifying the connection string name elsewhere? Search your solution for "MoveDBContext" to see if it's referenced anywhere else.

Comment: Find all "MoveDBContext", Match case, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
  C:\Users\...\MvcMovie\MvcMovie\Web.config(13):    <add name="MoveDBContext"
  Matching lines: 1    Matching files: 1    Total files searched: 93

Comment: @Primc - I just read your question a little closer. The error is with the 'AttachDbFilename' value. When the connection string is called 'MoveDBContext', EF isn't using it at all. When you change it to 'MovieDBContext', EF tries to use it but finds a problem with the connection string. Is your Movies2.mdf file being created as expected?

Comment: Actually I changed it from Movies.mdf to Movies2.mdf as a test and forgot to change it back. No, the file isn't being created at all, but the database and table are being created in my SQLExpress instance (as viewed through SQL Server Mgmt studio).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as Ken said, the MoveDBContext was not being referenced.

I removed the entire connectionString from the web.config and everything still functioned correctly.

So, it still begs the question, "How did Visual Studio know to create a database in my SQLExpress instance?" and "Where is that configured at?"